# Google+ API - insert/update status on Google+

Tags: php, google-plus, google-domain-api

I have a question about Google APIs. My goal is to post status to our Google+ company page from server. So it has to be server-side, completely.

I saw hundreds of pages from Google documentation, but I don't understand it at all.

When I try to execute action "plusDomains.activities.insert" (over API Explorer), I'm getting error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "plusDomains",
    "reason": "forbiddenScope",
    "message": "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes. See: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access to the Google+ Domains API is not allowed as the user has consented to incompatible scopes. See: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/."
 }
}
```

What is the reason of this error? And what user I have to use? In developers console I have 3 users and 1 full admin (my G-Apps account). What should I set as client-id and to google credentials object?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

The API Explorer has a bug where it defaults to scopes that are incompatible with Google+ Domains accounts. Go to the [Google account permissions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) list and revoke access from `Google APIs Explorer`. Go back to the APIs Explorer and authorize again but uncheck the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope leaving only `plus.me` and `plus.stream.write` scopes enabled.

Comment: Many thanks for answer. Now it gives me this error:

    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "plusDomains",
        "reason": "notDomainRestricted",
        "message": "The operation is not allowed because the activity is not domain restricted."
       }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "The operation is not allowed because the activity is not domain restricted."
      }
    }

Comment: That error is pretty self-explanatory. Look at the [activities.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert) documentation for `domainRestricted`.

Comment: Oh :-) Thanks, now I know. But now I have another error. When I set domainRestricted to true, I got this error:

{\n
_"error": {\n
__"code": 500,\n
__"message": null\n
_}\n
}\n

I don't know what to do with it. Am I doing right, that I'm using address <long-random-id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com as client e-mail address and another random ID as client ID (from Google Developers Console)? When I try to authorize with my user e-mail (on our google-apps domain), I got error "invalid_grant" and no longer gets access-token.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I had this working and suddenly it stopped working. after removing the access as mentioned by @abraham , it started working.. i wonder what is the issue.